# Integrate <i> to Html.Actionlink

Tags: html, css, html.actionlink

How can i integrate below code

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add</a>
```

to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "xx", "Law", new { _lawfileid = -1, baseappid = ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LawID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary icon-plus" })
```

I could not integrated `<i>` to Html.Actionlink.

**How can i integrate `<i>` to Html.Actionlink as class ?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Update:

**HtmlHelperActionLinkExtensions Class**

```
  public static IDisposable BeginActionLink<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            return new DisposableActionLink(htmlHelper.ViewContext, () => BeginLink(htmlHelper, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes), EndActionLink);
        }

        private static MvcHtmlString BeginLink(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName,
            RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
            var linkTag = new TagBuilder("a");
            linkTag.Attributes.Add("href", urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues));
            linkTag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(linkTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        }

        private static MvcHtmlString EndActionLink()
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create("</a>");
        }
```

**DisposableActionLink Class**

```
  public class DisposableActionLink : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TextWriter _writer;
        private Func<MvcHtmlString> End { get; set; }

        public DisposableActionLink(ViewContext viewContext, Func<MvcHtmlString> begin, Func<MvcHtmlString> end)
        {
            _writer = viewContext.Writer;
            End = end;
            _writer.Write(begin().ToHtmlString());
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _writer.Write(End().ToHtmlString());
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
@using Project.Models





   @Html.BeginActionLink("Add", "Law", new RouteValueDictionary { { "_lawfileid", "-1" }, 

{ "baseappid", ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LawID } }, new 

Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "btn btn-primary icon-plus" } })
    {
        <i class="icon-plus"></i>Add
    }
```

**Result Picture**

Normally icon must be +Add however it displays different things.

Picture

http://i.hizliresim.com/YPL6AZ.png

Comment: may you please help me about this thanks

Comment: what is not working? if you want the icon, then you should be able to get it, even for anchor element, no need to have i specifically :)

Comment: I want to integrate i to html actionlink class.If i can not add i to html.actionlink , html.actionlink displays different(small)

Comment: i don't think you can do it , "as class".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with your problem - is not to use Html.ActionLink. Yes, it doesnt support nested tags, but you can just do this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("xx", "Law", new { _lawfileid = -1, baseappid = ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LawID })" class="btn btn-primary icon-plus"><i class="icon-plus"></i>>Add</a>
```

**UPD:**
There is another workaround. Although it seems a bit hacky, the "hacky" thing will be incapsulated, so no one will know :)

```
public class DisposableActionLink : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TextWriter writer;
    private Func<MvcHtmlString> End { get; set; }

    public DisposableActionLink(ViewContext viewContext, Func<MvcHtmlString> begin, Func<MvcHtmlString> end)
    {
        writer = viewContext.Writer;
        End = end;
        writer.Write(begin().ToHtmlString());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        writer.Write(End().ToHtmlString());
    }
}

public static class HtmlHelperActionLinkExtensions
{
    public static IDisposable BeginActionLink<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        return new DisposableActionLink(htmlHelper.ViewContext, () => BeginLink(htmlHelper, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes), EndActionLink);
    }

    private static MvcHtmlString BeginLink(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName,
        RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var linkTag = new TagBuilder("a");
        linkTag.Attributes.Add("href", urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues));
        linkTag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(linkTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
    }

    private static MvcHtmlString EndActionLink()
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create("</a>");
    }
}
```

So now you can use it like:

```
@using (Html.BeginActionLink("xx", "Law", new RouteValueDictionary{{"_lawfileid", "-1"}, {"baseappid", ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LawID}}, new Dictionary<string, object>{{"class", "btn btn-primary icon-plus"}})
{
    <i class="icon-plus"></i>@:Add
}
```

Comment: Why do you need acitonlink so much? It has no functionality at all.

Comment: Yes, it will work, i have just tested it. But you need to change your occupation, or, at least, your boss. He's retarded.

Comment: Did you add references to your .cshtml file, @user3722851?

Comment: There are some typos from me. I have just updated the post, @user3722851.

Comment: That is not how you do it. You should add reference to that class, not pass it as a model. So you might wanna write @@using instead of @@model in this case, @user3722851

Comment: @user3722851, please, just copypaste my code from the bottom of my answer, and read about C#.

Comment: you are the best thank you so much.If you have skype , i can contact you because i alwayas ask questions if you want to  help me onstackoverflow by skype thanks again

Comment: @user3722851, better sign up to SO and mark my post as the answer :)

Comment: @user3722851, my skype is v_qilin

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.ActionLink(new MvcHtmlString("<i class='icon-plus'>Add</i>").ToHtmlString(), "xx", "Law", new { _lawfileid = -1, baseappid = ((ObjectModelLibrary.Law)ViewData["currentLaw"]).LawID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary"})`

Try this.

Comment: there is syntax error may you please check again thanks

Comment: updated. p.s don't have pc right now with me, writing from pad,sorry :)